# How can I integrate Amazon search results into my app?

Tags: ios, sdk, amazon-advertising-api

I was wondering how I can use the Amazon Search API in my iPhone app code.

I've looked around and can't really find any good usage examples.

My idea would be the lookup of a certain, specific Amazon product and the ability to let the user buy that item.

Any help would be great!

**Update:** I didn't mean ordering. I just mean the showing of product details and pricing and redirection to Amazon.com if they do want to order it.

Comment: doesn't the amazon principle pay you just for referring them and subsequent purchases made?  Why do you need to write the whole ordering part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Amazon's terms-of-service prohibit using their API to purchase products on a mobile device. I think Delicious Library got bit by this, or something close to it. Just a heads up.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. You cannot use Amazon's product information web services in a mobile application. It really sucks, but them's the breaks.

Comment: Anthony: none within their terms of service, no.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the text:
(e) You will not, without our express prior written approval, use any Product Advertising Content on or in connection with any site or application designed or intended for use with a mobile phone or other handheld device.

Not sure if anyone requested or got approved. But technically if you want to try it out, check this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtgr8-a3/