# Getting start with aws ios sdk to search books with their ISBN from iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios6, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS iOS SDK. I have installed AWS iOS SDK and also look the sample project given by AWS iOS SDK.
But unfortunately I didn't get anything suitable for me.

My simple task is to search books with their ISBN number on Amazon server.

Can I have sample Xcode project that is requesting "itemlookup" from AWS? 
OR
Can I have sample Xcode project that is making request to get item from AWS?

I have spent more then 8 hours on this but didn't find anything. Now atlast I come to SO. I hope that I'll get suitable help from here.

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a great discussion and help of Bob Kinney and Ryan Parman. I went to right path and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344084/how-can-i-integrate-amazon-search-results-into-my-app) on SO.
In this question the last answer has a link of Sorceforge sample code of 'amazon advertising api'

[Sample Code Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtgr8-a3/?source=dlp)

Although this code has some errors, which I solved by googling them, but at last I got the desired results.

Hope this will help you greatly...

Answer (score 2):

The AWS SDK for iOS is for accessing Amazon Web Services like S3, EC2, and DynamoDB.  What you are looking for is the [Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).  There are a number of [questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Amazon%20advertising%20API) that should give you some starting ideas.

Comment: Thanks for answering sir, Actually I am new to AWS SDK, I need to get book details from its ISBN, to be more simple, I want that when I give ISBN number to service, it should give me detail of book (if present on amazon server).

I am not getting the point that which will I have to use either S3, EC2 or DynamoDB.

Can you please help me....?

Comment: @azeem S3 is a storage service you can use to store files, EC2 a virtual server environment that could be used for any number of purposes, and DynamoDB is a NoSQL database.  If you are interested in learning more about these services, I recommend you read up on their appropriate pages on http://aws.amazon.com/.  You can also have a look at the samples included with the AWS SDK for iOS to see examples of how a number of the services could be used in a mobile application.

Comment: @azeem: More specifically, _Amazon Web Services_ is the name of Amazon's infrastructure services. The web service used to look up information about books is called the Product Advertising API and falls under _Amazon Associates_. As such, since the Advertising API is not part of AWS, the SDK does not have support for it.

Comment: @RyanParman :: Does your answer means that using AWS iOS SDK, I cann't get book information from Amazon server if I have ISBN number of that book?

Comment: @BobKinney : thanks for answering and clearing my concepts about AWS. Hope you'll not mind if I ask something more. I am usedto with `google api of book family`. As it uses only a simple url address and its response is the complete book detail. Is Amazon not offering any url/web service likewise google?

Comment: @azeem What Ryan says is true. The AWS SDK for iOS cannot be used for looking up books as that is not its purpose.  I recommend you look over the SO search I linked to as well as the Advertising API link.  I'm afraid I'm not familiar with these particular APIs, so can't offer much more assistance than that.

Comment: @azeem: Correct. Amazon's Product Advertising API _is not part of AWS_, therefore the _AWS SDK_ won't work with it.