# iOS Unable to use Books API on google

Tags: ios, google-api, google-search, isbn

I am scanning ISBN code and searching the book on the basis of that code on google in my iOS app. I created the app on google.I have keys for browser apps and I also created keys for iOS app.

Now here is the API I am using:-

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn=9783161484100&key={API Key}
```

When I am passing browser app key its giving fine results in my iOS app also.

But when I am passing iOS API Key , then its giving response like this:-

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

I knows that there are 1,000 request limit in a day. But I did only 18 request till now. Then why this response is coming from iOS API Key. Is there some other way to implement book search functionality in iOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703916/getting-start-with-aws-ios-sdk-to-search-books-with-their-isbn-from-iphone this link may helps you out. check it

Answer (score 1):

Is your bundle identifier in google api console and bundle id in Xcode project are same?

Answer (score 0):

There have been some issues w/ Google's API and Bundle IDs in their other apps. 
As such - (in the Youtube API as well), Google suggested creating an API Key for "any app".

To do this - 
In the Google Developer Console under your project's API & Auth:

Create New Key -> iOS Key, just click create with the bundle ID field left empty.